# Android, checkable menu item

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar, checked

I have a menu in my ActionBar, which is checkable (in XML), but when I try, in java, to check it on press on this item, the item stay unchecked (but the other things related to this action is done)

My XML menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    [...]
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_switch_full_original"
        android:title="@string/menu_switch_full_original"
        android:checkable="true"/>
</menu>
```

And the java code :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mEntriesIds != null) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            [...]
            case R.id.menu_switch_full_original: {
                item.setChecked(true);
                [...]
        }
        activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    return true;
}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
private boolean isChecked = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_switch_full_original);
         checkable.setChecked(isChecked);
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.a, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_switch_full_original:
            isChecked = !item.isChecked();
            item.setChecked(isChecked);
            // your other functionality
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if this should work using invalidateOptionsMenu?